# find control not able to find controls that created with literal control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

this is MyFirstRow in my .aspx file:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="MyFirstRow" runat="server">
```

I created the control with this Code in CodeBehind :

```
Control Con = FindControl("MyFirstRow");
LiteralControl LCx = new LiteralControl();
LCx.Text = @"<li class='dropdown' id='MyFirstRow34' runat='server'>
<a href='#'>Sample<span class='caret'></span></a></li>";
Con.Controls.Add(LCx);
```

so far everything is ok, but after next line when I use this code, this not able to find any control In the event that this added Correctly:

```
Con = FindControl("MyFirstRow34");
```

where is my mistake?
tnx for your response.

**Edited :**
 My question is how to access this control with id=MyFirstRow34 in Code-Behind?

Answer (score 0):

The `<li class='dropdown' id='MyFirstRow34' runat='server'>` string content assigned to the `LiteralControl` doesn't get interpreted by `ASP.NET`; this string is only part of the html output.

In order to find the control by the given Id, you must assign the Id to the controls `ID` property, as shown below.

```
LiteralControl LCx = new LiteralControl { ID = "MyFirstRow34" };
```

The full code of your example will look like this:

```
Control Con = FindControl("MyFirstRow");
LiteralControl LCx = new LiteralControl { ID = "MyFirstRow34" };
LCx.Text = @"
    <li class='dropdown'>
        <a href='#'>Sample<span class='caret'></span></a>
     </li>";
Con.Controls.Add(LCx);

Control myFirstRow34 = FindControl("MyFirstRow34");
```